# Squid to allow src ip address

Tags: linux, networking, docker, proxy, squid

I have a squid proxy running on a docker on linux with ip say a.b.c.d

Squid proxy is configured to allow only certain domains (dst) and block everything else. There is also a parent proxy configured so that all allowed domains are directed to parent and others are straightaway blocked by squid. This works as expected from inside the docker and also linux host.

Now I want to also allow a Windows PC connected to the Linux (pingable) with IP a.b.c.e

But now due to some reason the requests do not reach squid properly. Squid docker logs show :

> NONE_NONE/000 0 - error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE

My squid config is:

```
http_access deny all !<aclname>
acl <aclname2> src a.b.c.e
http_access allow <aclname2>

cache_peer <parent_proxy> parent 3128 0 no-query default
prefer_direct off
cache_peer_access <parent_proxy> allow <aclname>
never_direct allow all
```

Not sure if the order of acls matter. Also it is not just from one client. When I try a different setup, it occurs there as well.

Comment: use tcpdump or wireshark to capture traffic. I guess the logs will match HTTPS requests instead of HTTP requests to the proxy.

Comment: What kind of docker network do you use? If you want a container to be reachable from the host i would recommend using docker network_mode host using docker compose. Or create a custom docker network and make sure traffic is properly routed to the container. Please provide your docker-compose.yml